# Hyphen usage with 'off-limits'/'off limits'

Tags: hyphens

I have seen both 'off-limits' and 'off limits' used in the same context. A thing that is off(-)limits is forbidden to be used or otherwise restricted to only some people's usage from my understanding.

I'm asking if I should use a hyphen or not.

Comment: As I show in my answer, dictionaries can help with this.  A good dictionary will have example of the use of a phrase like "off-limits".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use it as a [compound word you can hyphenate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-limits) (though as you have discovered, [hyphenation is optional](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-limits))

When you use it as prepostion+noun then don't hyphenate, likewise if "off" is part of a phrasal verb.

> The forbidden forest is off-limits (or off limits) to all students.

> We have taken off limits on the number of people who can meet inside.

Comment: So when used as an adjective, it should be hyphenated (first example) and when it connects to a verb, it should not be (second example)? Redundant question, but just to be sure...

Comment: Yes.  In the second case it is not a compound word "off-limits" but two separate words "taken off" and "limits"  But look at the dictionary links for more examples.  Hyphenation is optional (though increasingly common)

Comment: We only have the second case in my language so I got a bit confused.